# Laravel response status code with no message

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to send back a response only with status code 204 and no body message?

With this for example you always send back a json:

```
response()->json($data, $code);
```

Comment: `response()->json(null, 204);` and you can do this if the request has `Accept: application/json` header: `return response(null,204)`

Comment: This question has solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178145/laravel-json-response-not-working-as-expected/53178394#53178394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

204 reponses do NOT have bodies.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Try responding like response(null, 204) -- not tested but it should work