# How to correctly return a JSON Response in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, response, laravel-6

```
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'No new orders!'
    ]);
```

Unfortunately, this response is not working? Ideally, I'd like to return a JSON response with 'Message' => 'No new orders!' with a status code 204 No Content.

I have these 2 included files in the controller...

```
use OhMyBrew\BasicShopifyAPI;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

This utilizes this built-in helper from ***vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/foundation/helpers.php***

```
if (! function_exists('response')) {
    /**
     * Return a new response from the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\View\View|string|array|null  $content
     * @param  int     $status
     * @param  array   $headers
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory
     */
    function response($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        $factory = app(ResponseFactory::class);

        if (func_num_args() === 0) {
            return $factory;
        }

        return $factory->make($content, $status, $headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be working though. `return response()->json(['message' => 'No new orders!'], 204);` Are you hitting the right endpoint? Have you tried to see if the request shows up in the network tab of the browser's element inspector?

Comment: @IGP Yep done that too. still not working. It's beyond me why it's not working even commented everything else out still doesn't wanna play...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178145/laravel-json-response-not-working-as-expected

Comment: How are you making this request?  If via javascript, is your request sending through the "Accept" header?  Something like `Accept: "application/json"`?

Comment: What do you mean about `not working`? You need to be more specific to the problem. If you mean your JS code can't get the desired response, so just show us your JS code!

Comment: Could you try to open your URL in the Postman? It's the best place to test your JSON response.

Answer (score 11):

To return data as json.. just do this:

```
public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $data = ['message' => 'No new orders!'];
    
    return response()->json($data, 204);
}
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/responses#json-responses):

> #### JSON Responses
>
> The json method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to
> `application/json`, as well as convert the given array to JSON using
> the `json_encode` PHP function:
>
> ```
> return response()->json([
>     'name' => 'Abigail',
>     'state' => 'CA'
> ]);
> ```

PS: The default response code returned is `200`, so, in case you want to return a 200 response code, you could omit the second param.

---

Notice that, in order to also receive error details in json format, it'll help that your front-end make the request telling your backend that it expects a json response. To do this, add this header when making requests:

```
accept: application/json
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing is content won't work when you use code 204. As you wrote status 204 means no content so if you put any content it won't be used.

So if you need to return content from your response, you need to use other status code (for example 200).

However:

```
 return response()->json([
        'message' => 'No new orders!'
    ]);
```

should work without any problem because status 200 is used here so if it doesn't work remove `vendor` directory and run again `composer install` because maybe you made some changes in vendor directory by accident. Also you should verify log file stored in `storage/logs` directory to verify the real problem.

Comment: Can we use `response()->json(....)` in controller's constructor? I have tried but it does not work. Any suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the response helper doesn't work, you may use this:

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json

Basically:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

return Response::json(['data' => 'data'], 200);
```

Comment: Getting error `Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory] is not instantiable`